# Optimized running time on two long polynomials' division

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, polynomial-math

In two long polynomials of degree n - 1's  division, obviously the reminders with coefficient can be calculated in O(n * n). I want to know if there is any faster algorithms to obtain the reminders, e.g. O(nlogn).

P.S(updated)clarify :if polynomials, p, q have different degree, where deg(p) > deg(q), Is it possible to find the remainders of p / q faster than O((deg(p)- deg(q)) * p) while accuracy don't lose?

Comment: If both polynomials `p`, `q` have the same degree (namly `deg(p)=deg(q)=n-1`) the division runs in `O(n)`. p/q is a real number `c` plus a remainder `p - c*q`

Comment: if polynomials, p, q have different degree, where deg(p) > deg(q), Is it possible to find the remainders of p / q faster than       O((deg(p)- deg(q)) * p) while accuracy don't lose?

Comment: I think in general computing `p/q` with `deg(p) = n >= m = deg(q)` takes `Theata((n-m+1)*n)`. If you have a special problem given it might be possible that there is a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

If the polynomials are of the same degree, you can determine with one operation the number of times one goes into the other (if the coefficients are integers, this will in general be a rational number). Then you can multiply that fraction times one polynomial and subtract it from the other. This takes O(n) field operations, which is optimal since the answer is of length Θ(n) in the average and worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a faster algorithm, however only for very large degrees. First reverse the polynomials, then use fast (Newton-based) Taylor series division  to compute the reversed quotient, reverse the quotient and compute the remainder using fast multiplication.

The first operation has the runtime of a multiplication of polynomials with the degree of the quotient, the second of a multiplication of polynomials of the degree of the divisor.